# Timestamps and timezones are broken and won't update in the Edge-browser-based PWA Microsoft Outlook and Teams apps

Tags: outlook-on-the-web, time-zone, microsoft-teams

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.

I run Microsoft Outlook, Teams, Word, Excel, etc., all in the Edge-browser-base PWA (Progressive Web Apps) apps using my enterprise work Microsoft account. See Microsoft's article here, for instance, on how to set them up: [Support.Microsoft.com: Use the web version of Outlook like a desktop app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-web-version-of-outlook-like-a-desktop-app-b360bd9a-00dc-43a4-bdf8-71cdeeb78e83).

They look like this in the sidebar in Ubuntu, for instance:

[image]

In Teams, however, the timestamps above each message are off by 7 hours, indicating that they are set to UTC minus 0, instead of UTC minus 7, which is my timezone.

My Ubuntu timezone and time is correct, and shows up correctly at the top of my screen.

I did just travel and cross 1 timezone 2 days ago.

In my Outlook settings, under: settings gear icon --> Calendar --> View --> Time zones, I do have my settings set correctly, as shown here:

[image]

In Teams, under 3-dots-at-top-right-near-my-photo --> Settings, I have searched all over all of the settings (some of which are shown below), and see no setting to fix timezonesor timestamps:

[image]

But, again, in Teams, the timestamps above each message are wrong, being 7 hours too fast in my case [note: the timestamp here is actually correct; I fixed it before being able to take this screenshot]:

[image]

I have closed and reopened all Outlook and Teams windows multiple times. It does not fix it.

This did not work for me either: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/solved-ms-teams-displays-the-wrong-time-timezone/12bc5b2a-160d-4f0b-b6c5-14fac461fd35

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to restart the entire Edge Browser. Remember: my PWA apps are Edge-browser-based even though they look like regular stand-alone programs on the PC.

So, open any tab in any open Edge Browser window, go to the search bar, and type this command:

```
edge://restart
```

This restarts the whole Edge browser and all Edge-browser-based PWA apps, such as Microsoft Teams and Outlook. The timestamps in Teams are now fixed back to local time!

In Outlook on the calendar page, after running the above restart command, a popup came up, like this:

[image]

I chose "Yes". That made my "AZ"-labeled timezone become the default (right-most) timezone in the calendar views, fixing that too, as shown here:

[image]

Outlook considers the one in the *right-most column* to be the "default" timezone currently being used.

---

### Is there an underlying bug in Chromium?

There seems to be an underlying bug in Chromium, perhaps. Both Chrome and Edge are based on the Chromium browser. I just noticed that in LinkedIn messages at https://www.linkedin.com/ in my Chrome browser I was having the same problem!: timestamps were ahead by 7 hours on all chat messages. So, I did the same thing in Chrome now too and it has fixed all timestamp issues in LinkedIn there too. In any Chrome window and tab, run this in the search bar:

```
chrome://restart
```

That restarts Chrome and fixes Chrome as well.